# Flatten function

Tags: scala

The Scala docs say the flatten api flattens a list of lists and it can only be invoked on a list of lists.

Why is it possible to invoke it on the following then?

```
List(Some("Tony"), None).flatten
```

Answer (score 10):

The ScalaDoc API shows the `[use case]` -- a simplified representation of the method signature.
If you click on the `Full signature` it will expand into the complete signature:

```
Full Signature
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

You can call `flatten` on lists, or on most other collections for that matter, as long as there is an implicit conversion from the list element type `A` (in your case `Option[String]`) to a traversable of any other type.

Any `Option` type can be implicitly converted into a `GenTraversableOnce` -- `Some` acts as a single element collection and `None` as an empty collection.
This means that you can call `flatten` on the `List[Option[String]]` to obtain a `List[String]`.